# CSS Elements Positioning

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to put two divs in the same "level" ,  for example:
------    ----------
|Eelem 1|  |Elem 2  |
--------   ----------
But so far elem1 is above elem2 .
I've added the relavant code , what am I able to do in order to fix it ?

Thanks in advance c

```
 <div class="stats">The expression <b>football</b> appeared 47 times in 44 different status messages</div><div class='hideDiv'><p class='toggleStats'>Hide Stats</p></div>run time is9.6276791095734 
            <div class="dropStatus">
                <p class="dropHeader">Drag , Drop & Share !</p>
                <p class="droppedStatus"><button class="clear" style="display:none">clear</button></p>
            </div>



.stats{
    margin-left : 20px;
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius : 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center; 
}


.dropStatus {
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.dropHeader{
    font-size : 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.droppedStatus{
    font-size : 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fjRAZ/

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to do this is to set `display` to `inline` or `inline-block`. Use `vertical-align` if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , in which element should I employ this setting ?

Comment: Apply it to the elements that are usually block-level, but that you want to be side-by-side.

Comment: In this case `.dropHeader` and `.droppedStatus`, if I've understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

```
.stats{
    margin-left : 20px;
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius : 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline; /* You can also use inline-block but might be problematic with ie*/
}


.dropStatus {
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: inline; /* You can also use inline-block but might be problematic with ie*/
}
```

Or:

```
.stats{
    margin-left : 20px;
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius : 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center; 
    float: left; /* added this */
}


.dropStatus {
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius: 12px;
    float: left; /* added this*/
}
```

Please note that floats might be a bit tricky, you can learn more [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/)

Comment: You could also use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` to get those elements displayed side-by-side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but it's still not working - http://jsfiddle.net/hGFv6/1/ take a look at the jsfiddle

Comment: You have another div between them: `hideDiv`, so either move it after `.dropStatus` div, or give it a `display:block-inline` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in the fact that `div` elements are so called [block elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), this means that you will have to apply CSS rules that prevent their default behavior and instead make them act like `inline` or `inline-block` elements.

By applying the styling rule `display:inline-block;` to those block elements they will instead start to act like blocks - but inline! (which is in many cases very useful.)

Worth noting, though, is that you might be required to add `vertical-align:top` to these elements as well in order for them to align properly.

Also, `inline-block` is not quite supported in earlier `Internet Explorer` version (e.g. 6 and 7), to work around this issue you can also add the rules `*display:inline; zoom:1;`, this will make the blocks act as intended in most scenarios.

I'll give you an example of this implementation below.

```
.stats{
    margin-left : 20px;
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius : 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center; 
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}


.dropStatus {
    width : 400px;
    height : 112px;
    background-color : #C1F756;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

http://jsfiddle.net/uLPT5/